# JPQL Exception "The right expression is missing from the logical expression."

Tags: jpql

I got the error "The right expression is missing from the logical expression." when running my JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I'd got `AND AND` in my JPQL (on separate lines annoyingly so it wasn't obvious to me)